# Understanding "Buffers" and "Cached" from free command

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, free-command

This has been asked earlier but don't want to update the same thread again as it was a old thread .

Want to clarify myself on the "buffers" and "cache" column from the output of `free` command.

This is what my understanding...

Buffer is something where data is there in memory but yet to be flushed to disk . 
The data will be flushed to disk by `bdflush` daemon periodically or we can do it manually by running `sync` command .

Cache on the other hand is program/data which is loaded into memory but is retained in memory so that if is needed again , it will be quickly available.

To understand the concept of buffers , I tried the following experiment...

This is the reading of `free` command in my desktop

```
[zama@localhost ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2897        465       2431          0         30        230
-/+ buffers/cache:        204       2692
Swap:         4000          0       4000

[zama@localhost ~]$ sync

[zama@localhost ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2897        466       2431          0         30        230
-/+ buffers/cache:        205       2691
Swap:         4000          0       4000
```

Here I cannot see buffer getting reduced after executing the `sync` command.

Next I tried the following...Tried to write a huge file to the disk .

```
[zama@localhost ~]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024k
```

As expected , the cached value should increase and free is confirming this..

```
@localhost ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2897       1466       1430          0         32       1127
-/+ buffers/cache:        306       2590
Swap:         4000          0       4000
```

I again executed the `sync` command and then checked using `free` . I can see that the buffer value getting decreased  from the output of `free` command . There was no reduction in the cache . This means that the dirty pages in RAM after my execution of `dd` coomand has been flushed to disk .

```
@localhost ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2897       1466       1430          0         10       1127
-/+ buffers/cache:        306       2590
Swap:         4000          0       4000
```

Then I updated the `drop_cache` kernel parameter so that the cache vlaue is dropped

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
0

[root@localhost ~]# echo "1" > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 

[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
1
```

`free` now confirms that both buffer and cache value is dropped.

```
[root@localhost ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2897        299       2597          0          1         74
-/+ buffers/cache:        224       2672
Swap:         4000          0       4000
```

So , my initial statement that "Buffer" is RAM data which is yet to be flushed to disk looks to be correct .

Please guide me whether I am in the right direction.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The column headers in the free command are somewhat mislabeled, at least from the point of view of a linux user (as opposed to developer). Below is a clarification of what the headings mean:

**total:** Yes, this is total ram.

**used:**  Slightly confusing. This is calculated as total - (free + buffers + cache)

**free:**  Yes, this pure free and untouched memory.

**shared:**  Memory specifically allocated for use by multiple processes

**buffers:** Temporary memory that is set aside to help some processes

**cache:**   Memory that is available and 'borrowed' by the operating system to help speed up many linux OS operations. This memory is given up by the system if an application need it.

The line that starts with **-/+ buffers/cache** is typically more helpful than the first **Mem** line. The intersection of **free** and **-/+ buffers/cache** is essentially what you have for 'available' memory.

Comment: Why would 'used' column include the memory being used for cache when there's a separate column for 'cache'?

Comment: @VishalSharma - yes you are right. used is actually calculated as: `total - (free + buffers + cache)`.

Answer (score 3):

The way I've always understood it is that the buffer area of memory is for temporary storage of data being read from or written to devices (including disks), while the cache area of memory is for speeding up future reads from a device.

Answer (score 3):

Linux vm sub-system treats any **free or unused or non-allocated** memory as **buffers/cache**

Therefore, running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` instructs the kernel to drop or clean the page caches (page-cache), dentries (slab-cache), and inodes (in the slab-cache) and causing the memory to become reclaimed and available.

Clean data cache pages are not freed by design. They can be easily reclaimed by the kernel if or when extra memory is to be allocated (malloc/calloc/brk/sbrk and friends), while they contain useful data from disks that if needed again saves doing a disk I/O.

`sync` command only commits any dirty pages in the memory to the disk, it does not free the buffers/cache. The only way to drop buffers/cache is by using `echo "1" > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` or the kernel reclaims the data pages for new allocated requested by applications

`pdflush` has been replaced by using flushing threads per backing device info (BDI).

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Memory_Usage_and_Page_Cache.html):

> Linux always tries to use RAM to speed up disk operations by using available memory for buffers (file system metadata) and cache (pages with actual contents of files or block devices).

---

Quoting from [serverFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free/85481#85481)

`shared` / `buffers` / `cached`: This shows memory usage for specific purposes, these values are included in the value for `used`.

The second line gives first-line values adjusted. It gives the original value for `used` minus the sum `buffers+cached` and the original value for free plus the sum `buffers+cached`, hence its title. These new values are often more meaningful than those of the first line.

The last line `Swap` gives information about swap space usage. For example memory contents that have been temporarily moved to disk.

Answer (score 1):

This is my understanding: the buffers tells you how much memory is reserved for maintaining block devices, but cache tells you how many memory is used for *file* contents.